# LiveCD for LFS 7.0

Tags: livecd, lfs

Most of the live CD systems I have come across don't seem to have the LFS requirements pre-installed (i.e. everything on [this list](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/prologue/hostreqs.html)).

Are there any live CD systems that come with the required software for LFS 7.0 preinstalled?

I have used the LFS liveCD in the past, but it looks like it is too out of date to be used with book 7.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could **build your own**.  While this clearly seems to be a chicken-and-egg problem, I just had a deeper look at [SUSE Studio](http://susestudio.com) and it could be of great use here.  Just login/create an account, choose a **base template** (say, "minimal X"), add software, choose "Live CD" in the **Build** tab.

Since all OpenSUSE repositories are available, you should find everything that's needed.  Plus, when your finished, you can **Share** the image as *"OpenSUSE LiveCD that supports everything needed for LFS 7.0"*

Answer (score 0):

I follwed sr_'s advice and made a quick minimal x build for parted, added a few things like wget and the current LFS wget-list url file.  http://susestudio.com/a/Ddud1R/lfs-71

Answer (score 0):

if you read lfs documentation more carefully, then you discover: prerequisities(this is just a one) bash-3.2(NEWER VERSIONS IS NOT TESTED!)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, which asks to mention any existing distributions that satisfy the LFS requirements, rather than just mentioning one of the requirements.